# Graphic Character prints when reading a file from the command line

Tags: c

My program takes in the Constitution, reverses the line order, and prints the Constitution in reverse order back in the command line. When I put the algorithm to reverse the lines in a separate function, lineReversal, the only thing that prints is ▒▒▒.

```
int main(){

char * buffer;

char * strings[1000]; 


int arrayCount =0;
int size = 10;

while(!feof(stdin))
{
    buffer= (char*) malloc(size);
    getAline(&buffer, &size); //gets each line from the Constitution

    strings[arrayCount++] = buffer;
}

lineReversal(&strings);

return 0;
}

char lineReversal(char ** stringPtr)
{
char * strings = *stringPtr;

for(int i = 873; i >=0 ; i--) {
    if(strings[i] == '\0'){
        break;
    }
    printf("%s", strings + i);
}

*stringPtr = strings;
return 0;
}
```

If I put that algorithm into main() and run my program, this is my output:

```
H▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒Dhave intervened.Representatives, shall take effect, until an election of Representatives shall
```

The expected output is:

```
have intervened.
```

This is what my program looks like with the algorithm inside main.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){

char * buffer;

char * strings[1000]; 


int arrayCount =0;
int size = 10;

while(!feof(stdin))
{
    buffer= (char*) malloc(size);
    getAline(&buffer, &size);

    strings[arrayCount++] = buffer;
}

for(int i = 873; i >=0 ; i--)
    {
    if(strings[i] == '\0'){
        break;
    }
    printf("%s", strings[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it print **junk**? :)

Comment: `i = 873`?? Magic numbers in code are very bad. What is 873 supposed to be??

Comment: For one thing, please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). For another there are probably very few text lines in your document which have only `9` characters - `int size = 10; ... buffer= (char*) malloc(size);`

Comment: `getAline` looks suspicious, why do you pass the address of `buffer`? buffer itself is already pointing to the buffer that you should pass. you also would be better off setting the last entry to point to NULL, that way you do not need to keep track of some magic number 873 i.e. `for (int i =0; strings[i] != NULL; ++i) {...}`

Comment: @kaylum 873 is the number of lines in the Constitution. I realize this is bad code, it was just a quick way for me to loop backwards through the array.

Comment: So you are asking why code that you realise is bad, does not work?

Comment: Curious: What reference (person, book, URL, etc. ) suggested to use `while(!feof(stdin))`?

Comment: @Anders K. `getAline()` looks like a modified `getline()`.  Passing the address of the buffer pointer and address of the size is required with that function.

Comment: @chux My C professor recommended we use it

Comment: @Emma Barrett  Thanks.  If the prof recommended exactly as you used it, watch out for subsequent "good ideas" from the prof.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with `getAline(&buffer, &size);`, check its return value.  Suggest change to  `for(int i = arrayCount; i >0 ; )  { printf("%s", strings[--i]);
}`